# Set focus on date field in DateTimePicker control in Windows form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datetimepicker

I've a `DateTimePicker` control in my code. And I have used a custom format.

```
this.dateTimePickerDate.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
this.dateTimePickerDate.Value = System.DateTime.Now;
```

Now the requirement is to focus on the date part of the control. For example if this control shows 30/06/2011, after the form_load, then `30` from the date part should be selected or the cursor will be after the `0` in `30`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this code helps:

```
dateTimePicker1.GotFocus += new EventHandler(dateTimePicker1_GotFocus);

void dateTimePicker1_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SendKeys.Send("{RIGHT 1}");
}
```

And on form load set focus to datetimepicker.

Comment: As my date field is in the left, so it will be right to write the code as `SendKeys.Send("{RIGHT 0}");` to set the focus on the date field.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested [here](http://www.dotnetmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/winform-controls/5529/Programmatically-select-day-subfield-in-datetime-picker), I don't think that's possible.

In that link is also suggested a tricky workaround (i.e. programmatically press the arrow to the right when the datetimepicker has got the focus) but that could lead to unexpected side-effects.