# C# - DateTimePicker in time format does not focus on the hour value when tabbing to next box

Tags: c#, datagridview, datetimepicker

I haven't found anything similar on numerous websites, so I hope you guys can help.

I have a datagrid for a timesheet system, so the specific cells for the time in/out etc have been set to `dateTimePickers` (using an override calandar class).

If the user puts in `08:00` and tabs to the next dtp, the focus is defaulted to the hour. However, if the user puts in `08:30` (they have put the hour in, then pressed the right arrow key to move to minutes), and then presses tab, the focus on the next dtp remains on minutes.

Is there a way to set the focus in the code or something to default to hour on each dtp?

Comment: I believe `DatetimePicker` doesn't expose anything which will let you know or change the focus of the parts within it, probably will have to live with it and use the arrow keys only.

Comment: Derive your own control from DTP and call RecreateHandle() to reset the focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on my comment i don't see in any way DateTimePicker exposing the current selection nor does it allow specifying any SelectionLength for the text it holds. So i don't think this can be possible.

On a different thought there is an **ugly hack** *(not recommended)* which i believe is **no better than the situation you have at end**.

[Found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6534625/570150) you may try in either of the events

```
void dateTimePicker1_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //SendKeys.Send("{LEFT 1}");
}

void dateTimePicker1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //SendKeys.Send("{LEFT 1}");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I tried in a simple form with three dtp and created a dtp_Enter event to containing dtp.focus(). This seemed to work when tabbing around. However, as mine is on a datagrid which is created at run time I'm not able to create an event, so think I'll just have to live with it

Comment: Not really, your editing control would be derived from datetimepicker so in the constructor you could subscribe to the event like `this.Enter` or `this.GotFocus`

Comment: Yeah I managed to find the bit in the class that does this. As per the ugly hack comments in the link, if you sent it to move left 1 it does this every time a cell is entered, so don't think that would make sense. I don't think there is anyway to detect where the focus is and only make it happen when the focus is on the right (minutes) side.

Comment: yeah .. thats why the note *no better than the situation you have at end* :)